# How to use variable command in a if statement

Tags: bash, sed

How to use the output of the variable `STATUS` in the following if statement?

I don't understand why the following if statement does not work.

```
$ declare STATUS=$(cat file.txt| grep 'relation": "next' | sed 's/^.*": *//;q' )
$ echo $STATUS
"next",

if test "$STATUS" = "next,"
then
    echo "YES"
fi
```

Also if possible, how to remove the caracters `,` and `"`

I could do something like

- original command: `sed 's/^.*": *//;q'`
- to remove `"` do this: `sed 's/"//;q'`
- to remove `,` do this: `sed 's/,//;q'`

But it would be best having only one sed command that does all

Comment: Don't parse json with grep/sed/etc. use `jq`

Comment: Two `"` are part of STATUS' content.

Comment: Add your JSON file to your question.

Comment: In general, any `cat | grep | sed` pipeline can be replaced by a single `awk` command.

Comment: If you provided a syntactically valid JSON file with the same format as your real input in the question, we'd be able to build answers that follow Diego's advice to actually parse that content _as JSON_, instead of trying to guess at its semantics via string-munging (which is an approach doomed to failure).

Comment: Let me give you an example of what I mean: Let's say the next version of your file has `"foo": "bar", "relation": "next-something"` both on the same line because the folks producing that file turned on compact-mode output (something most JSON libraries support). Any standard-compliant JSON parser doesn't care, but your `grep | sed` approach will include `bar` in what it extracts.

Comment: As for the immediate problem, though -- use `set -x` or `bash -x yourscript` to turn on trace-level logging. Maybe you'll see something like `+ test $'next,\r' = 'next,'`, which would tell you that your file has DOS newlines. Or maybe you'll see `+ test '"next",' = 'next,'`, which would tell you that the comparison is failing because you left out the literal quotes (`next,` and `"next",` are two different literal strings, but when you use `"next",` in an unquoted context the double quotes are consumed and not given to `test`; that's why it's important to put them in single quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all the substitutions in single `sed` like this:

```bash
sed -E 's/^.*": *|[",]+//g'
```

btw both `cat` and `grep` are not required, just use `sed`:

```bash
status=$(sed -E '/relation": "next/ s/^.*": *|[",]+//g' $FILE_NAME.json)

# check variable
declare -p status

# compare it
if [[ $status = "next" ]]; then
   echo "YES"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, the if statement still does not work, do you have any hints?

Comment: Can you try my updated script and tell me output of `declare -p` command

Comment: thanks alot for the help @anubhava.
I realized I forgot to mention an important detail.. the `status` var is inside of a function

the output og `declare -p` is `script.sh: line 80: declare: status: not found`

Comment: If `status` is not local then it should be available outside the function as well. May be if you update the question with your actual script then I can suggest something.

Comment: When you don't need status: `if grep -q 'relation": "next,"'; then ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the question of why the current `if/test` fails ...

To better understand what `bash` sees we'll turn on debugging (`set -x`):

```
$ set -x
$ if test "$STATUS" = "next,"; then echo "YES"; fi
+ test '"next",' = next,
```

From this we see the first issue ... `$STATUS` includes a set of double quotes within the value of the variable while the other side of the comparison does not.

One idea to make sure the double quotes are included in the content of the right side of the test:

```
$ if test "$STATUS" = '"next",'; then echo "YES"; fi
+ test '"next",' = '"next",'
```

From this we see the 2nd issue ... comma inside the double quotes on the left, comma outside the double quotes on the right.

Move the comma inside the double quotes:

```
$ if test "$STATUS" = '"next,"'; then echo "YES"; fi
+ test '"next",' = '"next",'
+ echo YES
YES
```

At this point we've got the desired result, ie, `YES` is printed to stdout.

---

An alternative approach that strips the double quotes out of the left side of the comparison via parameter substitution:

```
$ if test "${STATUS//\"/}" = "next,"; then echo "YES"; fi
+ test next, = next,
+ echo YES
YES
```

NOTES:

- `${STATUS//\"/}"` says to replace the literal `"` with nothing (ie, remove them)
- the double quotes are still contained within the contents of `STATUS`; we've merely removed them from what `bash` sees when running the comparison